# Bootstrap: Links to tabs in navigation bars stay active even when tab changes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have multiple navigation bars in one page:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about" data-toggle="tab">About</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about" data-toggle="tab">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

The status of a LI element becomes *active* when the belonging link was clicked. Problem: It stays *active* even when the user switches the tab in the other navigation.

It is not possible to switch back in the first navigation as the LI is already *active* there and can not be clicked. Things get even worse if you add a *div.collapse.navbar-collapse* in the main navigation bar and a simple link somewhere in the page:

```
<p><a data-toggle="tab" href="#about">About</a></p>
```

Answer (score 4):

In many cases different nav (with tabs) will open a new page or interact on difference elements in the page. In your case being active of nav1 only will be a problem when nav2 removes or change the content related to your nav1 active state.

You could try to remove the active states with the tab event, see http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs. For your example this will be come something like;

```
    $('.nav').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {
    $('.nav .active').removeClass('active');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to set the *active* class manually in all the navs after each tab switch.

```
$(function() {
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {

  // add active class where nav entry is active
  $('.nav a[data-toggle="tab"][href="'+$(e.target).attr("href")+'"]')
    .parent().addClass('active');

  // remove active class where nav entry is no longer active
  $('.nav a[data-toggle="tab"][href!="'+$(e.target).attr("href")+'"]')
    .parent().removeClass('active');

});
});
```